# Failed to authenticate Virtual Center Server due to network failure

Tags: esxi, vsphere, vmware-horizon

I am attempting to setup a Vmware horizon proof in concept for my firm.
I am using trial version of all of the below software, so latest and greatest from https://www.vmware.com/try-vmware.html

I am getting the following error:

[image: Horizon Error]

My Setup:

- 10.150.45.89 - ESXi
- 10.150.45.90 - Win2k9 (With Horizon Server installed)
- 10.150.45.91 - vSphere
- 10.150.45.92 - Win2k9 (With Horizon Server installed)

My Testing:

- I can log into the the admin webpage of all 3 of these servers. (eg all have network connectivity to/from my desktop)
- Servers .90 and .91 are both VMs on .89 though I have tried spinning up .90 on a different server to see if it would make a difference (it didn't)
- When attempting to get Horizon to connect to the VSphere server it prompts me to accept the self signed cert (meaning it pulled it over TCP/IP ... eg the network connection is working)
- I ran `Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 10.150.45.91 -Port 443` and got the following responce
  [image]

My Question:  What am I doing wrong? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was resolved, just putting the solution here for others who may run into it.

Once the vCenter appliance is deployed, you have to change the hostname, and the hostname must be resolved in DNS (via A-record).  Once fully configured, you can log into it and add hosts to manage.

This then allowed Horizon to add the vCenter server.